# These .htaccess commands aren't playing nice together

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a wordpress install in /, which has the following .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have a small internal photo-archive page  in /photo-archive, which has the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /photo-archive/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "Photo-Archive-Test"
#AuthUserFile "passwd"
#require valid-user
```

What's listed above works, but the photo-archive isn't password protected (since those lines are commented out).

Testing:

1. When I uncomment those lines, instead of getting the photo-archive front page and a password prompt, I get wordpress's 404 page.
2. If I comment out wordpress's .htaccess and uncomment all of the lines in the photo-archive's .htaccess, then I get the photo-archive's page with password protection.
3. If I comment out the photo-archive's rewriteengine stuff and uncomment the password stuff, then I still get wordpress's 404 page.

So it seems that somehow wordpress is picking up on the fact that the page is password protected and then is applying its rewriteEngine code as a result.

Any idea what's going on here or how to fix it?

Edit: There is only one line causing the problem: require valid-user

Edit2: After doing some research online, it seems like what's happening is apache is going to the photo-archive page, getting a 401 (unauthorized) error, tries to give that error to the browser, the browser looks that page up somehow, and wordpress serves up its 404 page, since it doesn't have a 401 page. I don't know how to fix it, but I think this may be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "ErrorDocument 401 /401.html" to the top of the wordpress's .htaccess file.

401.html is just a simple html file right now, it could be anything:

`<html>401 error</html>`

I got the answer from here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-and-subdirectories

> .htaccess files are additive. Whenever you request a page, the webserver basically goes through every directory down the tree from the root (specified by the closest match of  in the httpd.conf file), and adds all the .htaccess files together. As it traverses them, it parses each one. Later .htaccess files override previous ones, but only for the same specified items. RewriteRules are cumulative.
>
> So what I think is going on is that the authorization in the password protected directory is forcing a 401 response ("Authorization Required") back to the client. Normally, the client would get the 401 and ask for a password.
>
> However, in this case, this 401 response is intercepted by the WordPress RewriteRules which says to rewrite everything to WordPress. This is because .htaccess's are cumulative and your closest matching Directory is the root.
>
> So, by forcing an ErrorDocument for the 401 response before the WordPress rules, you pre-empt them (since the file actually exists, the RewriteRules won't take effect upon it), causing your 401 document to be sent instead of rewriting to WordPress. However, the client doesn't give a crap about that document, it sees the 401 and asks for a password.
>
> Notice that if you fail to give a password three times (depending on the client), you'll probably get forwarded back to WordPress. This may or may not be what you want. If you add the 403 line, you'll get either your error document or a 403 Forbidden page back, not certain which.
>
> Other possible solutions:
>   - Add a new Directory statement to httpd.conf, specifically specifying your password protected directory, thus bypassing the wordpress rewrites from the htaccess search path.
>   - Add another rewrite to the top of the wordpress rewrites that pre-empts them for that directory only.
>
> But forcing a 401/403 document seems like the best solution to me, since it will work with any password protected subdirectories you care to add, without having to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your WP .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/photo-archive [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Trying it now.

Comment: I just retested this whole setup and it worked. Only thing you should change is try giving **full filesystem path** for password file like `/home/user/www/passwd`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this further.  I am including the full path (I edited it out of my original post to avoid posting too much specific info), but still getting the error.  Take a look at my second edit above.  I'm pretty sure that's what's happening.

Comment: But 401 shouldn't come before auth dialog. Can you check your Apache error.log for some possible error text. Also try: `AuthUserFile "/path/to/passwd"` and make sure there is no trailing whitespace.

Comment: Anubhava: I don't have access to my apache error log. You should also check out the answer I found below.  It seems this is a relatively common problem.  I really appreciate your help.  Even though the answer didn't work out for my particular problem in the end, I am very grateful for it.

Comment: Actually I tried exactly same setup on my Apache but it didn't throw any 404. I will try to reproduce it on a WP install to see this can be reproduced.